# django import template from file

Tags: python, html, django

I have 3 pages, and all of them have the same menu on the top of each html file.

There are many a tags in the menu, and I have problem when I'd like to revised all link in a tag.

I'd like to write the menu in other file called menu.txt, and use template to load the menu.txt and then combine menu with other parts of the page.

Is there any efficiency way to do it?

Except load the page in view.py and pass value to template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Template inheritance**

The most powerful – and thus the most complex – part of Django’s template engine is template inheritance. Template inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override.

It’s easiest to understand template inheritance by starting with an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This template, which we’ll call base.html, defines a simple HTML skeleton document that you might use for a simple two-column page. It’s the job of “child” templates to fill the empty blocks with content.

In this example, the block tag defines three blocks that child templates can fill in. All the block tag does is to tell the template engine that a child template may override those portions of the template.

A child template might look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}My amazing blog{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% for entry in blog_entries %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The extends tag is the key here. It tells the template engine that this template “extends” another template. When the template system evaluates this template, first it locates the parent – in this case, “base.html”.

you can refer for extending commom part on each html page

http://www.webforefront.com/django/createreusabledjangotemplates.html

Comment: @Jimmy hope it will solve your problem have a nice day :)

Answer (score 16):

Use `include` in your template file. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

#### Example

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'includes/menu.html' %}
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<!-- ... -->
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Which file should I render in view? base or section file ?